# how to find out if virtual keypad is shown BB Cascades

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I would like to know, if the virtual keypad is shown or not on BB10 devices (fulltouch).
I'm using C++ / QML.

Answer (score 0):

There is a GitHub BlackBerry Community project called [smart signals](https://github.com/blackberry/Cascades-Community-Samples/tree/master/SmartSignals) that provides a link between BlackBerry Platform Services (BPS) and Cascades. In that project they define a VirtualKeyboarServices class that will emit signals when the virtual keyboard is shown, hidden and give you its height. That is where I would start.